# Can VBScript Escape() function be used in .Net..?

Tags: asp.net, vbscript

I'm puzzled by the Escape function that worked great in my .asp web page but doesn't work in a .Net aspx web page;

A variable is declared thus;

```
Dim sProtocols As String
```

This content is loaded into the sProtocols variable (by reading a file);

```
[EML Email forwarding]
ServiceName=EML FORWARD
ProtocolKey=SMTP_ANY_DESTN
PortBaudRate=
PortDataBits=
PortParity=
PortStopBits=
PortFlowControl=OFF
DialNumber=
ServicePrompt=
ServiceLogoff=
CarrierPrefix=
AccessKey=
MaxPages=999
MaxLength=250
MaxAttempts=1
X25NUA=
X25Prompt=your.domain.com
```

The Escape function is then called on contents of sProtocols;

```
sTemp = Escape(sProtocols)
```

Here is the perfectly formed output that can be embedded in the web page;

> %5BEML%20Email%20forwarding%5D%0D%0AServiceName%3DEML%20FORWARD%0D%0AProtocolKey%3DSMTP_ANY_DESTN%0D%0APortBaudRate%3D%0D%0APortDataBits%3D%0D%0APortParity%3D%0D%0APortStopBits%3D%0D%0APortFlowControl%3DOFF%0D%0ADialNumber%3D%0D%0AServicePrompt%3D%0D%0AServiceLogoff%3D%0D%0ACarrierPrefix%3D%0D%0AAccessKey%3D%0D%0AMaxPages%3D999%0D%0AMaxLength%3D250%0D%0AMaxAttempts%3D1%0D%0AX25NUA%3D%0D%0AX25Prompt%3Dyour.domain.com%0D%0A%

However, in the .Net aspx version of the web page I get these errors;

> [FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.]
>   Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.Conversions.ParseDouble(String Value, NumberFormatInfo NumberFormat) +213
>   Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.Conversions.ToInteger(String Value) +90
>
> [InvalidCastException: Conversion from string "[EML Email forwarding]
>   ServiceN" to type 'Integer' is not valid.]
>   Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.Conversions.ToInteger(String Value) +238
>   ASP.emi2_aspx.__Render__control1(HtmlTextWriter __w, Control parameterContainer) in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\EmsgwebOUT_NETEDITW.aspx:188
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children) +268
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer) +13
>   System.Web.UI.Page.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) +29
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +66
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +100
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer) +25
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1303

I don't understand, it always worked before and Escape is such an simple function to use.

Do I need to do something else to prepare the string for the Escape function or is there an alternative way of doing this?

Comment: You must be looking for [HttpServerUtility.UrlEncode Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zttxte6w(v=vs.110).aspx) ... VBScript != VB.Net

Comment: Thanks Filburt, but not quite due to UrlEncode not encoding space to %20 apostrophe to %27 and retaining the + character

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using one of the C#  alternatives:

```
string s = @"[EML Email forwarding]
ServiceName=EML FORWARD
ProtocolKey=SMTP_ANY_DESTN
PortBaudRate=
PortDataBits=
PortParity=
PortStopBits=
PortFlowControl=OFF
DialNumber=
ServicePrompt=
ServiceLogoff=
CarrierPrefix=
AccessKey=
MaxPages=999
MaxLength=250 -
MaxAttempts=1
X25NUA=
X25Prompt=your.domain.com";

string s2 = System.Uri.EscapeDataString(s);

Console.WriteLine(s2);
```

> %5BEML%20Email%20forwarding%5D%0D%0AServiceName%3DEML%20FORWARD%0D%0AProtocolKey%3DSMTP_ANY_DESTN%0D%0APortBaudRate%3D%0D%0APortDataBits%3D%0D%0APortParity%3D%0D%0APortStopBits%3D%0D%0APortFlowControl%3DOFF%0D%0ADialNumber%3D%0D%0AServicePrompt%3D%0D%0AServiceLogoff%3D%0D%0ACarrierPrefix%3D%0D%0AAccessKey%3D%0D%0AMaxPages%3D999%0D%0AMaxLength%3D250%0D%0AMaxAttempts%3D1%0D%0AX25NUA%3D%0D%0AX25Prompt%3Dyour.domain.com

Comment: Thanks! I was a liitle put off by the C#, however it also seems to work in VBScript by calling this (acknowledge user "dtb"); sTemp = Uri.EscapeDataString(sProtocols)